# Magento 2 - Created new table and model - but model does not save!

Tags: magento2, module, database, model, save

I created a new table `company_shipping_quote` and new models by using https://mage2gen.com/.

But how can I create a new object and save it so that it appears in the database?

## Models:

**Company/Shipping/Model/Quote:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Company\Shipping\Model;

use Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterface;
use Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;

class Quote extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    protected $quoteDataFactory;

    protected $dataObjectHelper;

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'company_shipping_quote';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param QuoteInterfaceFactory $quoteDataFactory
     * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param \Company\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Quote $resource
     * @param \Company\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Collection $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        QuoteInterfaceFactory $quoteDataFactory,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        \Company\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Quote $resource,
        \Company\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Collection $resourceCollection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->quoteDataFactory = $quoteDataFactory;
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve quote model with quote data
     * @return QuoteInterface
     */
    public function getDataModel()
    {
        $quoteData = $this->getData();

        $quoteDataObject = $this->quoteDataFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
            $quoteDataObject,
            $quoteData,
            QuoteInterface::class
        );

        return $quoteDataObject;
    }
}
```

**Company/Shipping/Model/QuoteRepository:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Company\Shipping\Model;

use Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterfaceFactory;
use Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteSearchResultsInterfaceFactory;
use Company\Shipping\Api\QuoteRepositoryInterface;
use Company\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Quote as ResourceQuote;
use Company\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory as QuoteCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class QuoteRepository implements QuoteRepositoryInterface
{

    private $collectionProcessor;

    protected $resource;

    protected $quoteFactory;

    protected $dataQuoteFactory;

    protected $extensibleDataObjectConverter;
    protected $searchResultsFactory;

    protected $dataObjectProcessor;

    private $storeManager;

    protected $quoteCollectionFactory;

    protected $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor;

    protected $dataObjectHelper;


    /**
     * @param ResourceQuote $resource
     * @param QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
     * @param QuoteInterfaceFactory $dataQuoteFactory
     * @param QuoteCollectionFactory $quoteCollectionFactory
     * @param QuoteSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResultsFactory
     * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param CollectionProcessorInterface $collectionProcessor
     * @param JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor
     * @param ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResourceQuote $resource,
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        QuoteInterfaceFactory $dataQuoteFactory,
        QuoteCollectionFactory $quoteCollectionFactory,
        QuoteSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResultsFactory,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CollectionProcessorInterface $collectionProcessor,
        JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor,
        ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter
    ) {
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->quoteCollectionFactory = $quoteCollectionFactory;
        $this->searchResultsFactory = $searchResultsFactory;
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        $this->dataQuoteFactory = $dataQuoteFactory;
        $this->dataObjectProcessor = $dataObjectProcessor;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->collectionProcessor = $collectionProcessor;
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor = $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor;
        $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter = $extensibleDataObjectConverter;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function save(
        \Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterface $quote
    ) {
        /* if (empty($quote->getStoreId())) {
            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $quote->setStoreId($storeId);
        } */

        $quoteData = $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter->toNestedArray(
            $quote,
            [],
            \Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterface::class
        );

        $quoteModel = $this->quoteFactory->create()->setData($quoteData);

        try {
            $this->resource->save($quoteModel);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__(
                'Could not save the quote: %1',
                $exception->getMessage()
            ));
        }
        return $quoteModel->getDataModel();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function get($quoteId)
    {
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
        $this->resource->load($quote, $quoteId);
        if (!$quote->getId()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Quote with id "%1" does not exist.', $quoteId));
        }
        return $quote->getDataModel();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getList(
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria
    ) {
        $collection = $this->quoteCollectionFactory->create();

        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process(
            $collection,
            \Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterface::class
        );

        $this->collectionProcessor->process($criteria, $collection);

        $searchResults = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
        $searchResults->setSearchCriteria($criteria);

        $items = [];
        foreach ($collection as $model) {
            $items[] = $model->getDataModel();
        }

        $searchResults->setItems($items);
        $searchResults->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());
        return $searchResults;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function delete(
        \Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterface $quote
    ) {
        try {
            $quoteModel = $this->quoteFactory->create();
            $this->resource->load($quoteModel, $quote->getQuoteId());
            $this->resource->delete($quoteModel);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw new CouldNotDeleteException(__(
                'Could not delete the Quote: %1',
                $exception->getMessage()
            ));
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function deleteById($quoteId)
    {
        return $this->delete($this->get($quoteId));
    }
}
```

**Company/Shipping/Model/Data/Quote.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Company\Shipping\Model\Data;

use Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterface;

class Quote extends \Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractExtensibleObject implements QuoteInterface
{

    /**
     * Get quote_id
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getQuoteId()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::QUOTE_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Set quote_id
     * @param string $quoteId
     * @return \Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterface
     */
    public function setQuoteId($quoteId)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::QUOTE_ID, $quoteId);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::ID);
    }

    /**
     * Set id
     * @param string $id
     * @return \Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterface
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::ID, $id);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve existing extension attributes object or create a new one.
     * @return \Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteExtensionInterface|null
     */
    public function getExtensionAttributes()
    {
        return $this->_getExtensionAttributes();
    }

    /**
     * Set an extension attributes object.
     * @param \Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setExtensionAttributes(
        \Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
    ) {
        return $this->_setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
    }

    /**
     * Get express_note
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getExpressNote()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::EXPRESS_NOTE);
    }

    /**
     * Set express_note
     * @param string $expressNote
     * @return \Company\Shipping\Api\Data\QuoteInterface
     */
    public function setExpressNote($expressNote)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::EXPRESS_NOTE, $expressNote);
    }
}
```

**Company/Shipping/Model/ResourceModel/Quote.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Company\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel;

class Quote extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('company_shipping_quote', 'quote_id');
    }
}
```

**Company/Shipping/Model/ResourceModel/Quote/Collection.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Company\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Quote;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'quote_id';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            \Company\Shipping\Model\Quote::class,
            \Company\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Quote::class
        );
    }
}
```

## Database

[image]

**Company/Shipping/etc/db_schema.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="company_shipping_quote" resource="default">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" nullable="false" unsigned="true" comment="ID"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>

        <column xsi:type="int" name="quote_id" nullable="false" unsigned="true" comment="Quote ID"/>
<!--        <constraint xsi:type="foreign"
                    referenceId="FK_QUOTE_ENTITIY_ID"
                    table="company_shipping_quote"
                    column="quote_id"
                    referenceTable="quote"
                    referenceColumn="entity_id"
                    onDelete="CASCADE"/>-->

        <column xsi:type="text" name="express_note" nullable="true" comment="Express Shipping Note with Additional Information"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Of course I executed `bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile`

## Attempt:

Now inside another class I tried to create an object of the model and save it:

```
protected $_companyShippingQuoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Company\Shipping\Model\QuoteFactory $companyShippingQuoteFactory
) {
    ...
    $this->_companyShippingQuoteFactory = $companyShippingQuoteFactory;
}

...

$quoteModel = $this->_companyShippingQuoteFactory->create();
$quoteModel->setQuoteId(123);
$quoteModel->setExpressNote("foo_bar");
$quoteModel->save();
```

But it does not save. The database table is still empty:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to your: db_schema.xml

Try to add:

```
 <column xsi:type="int" name="id" nullable="false" unsigned="true" comment="ID" identity="true"/>
```

Adding identity="true"

If you check e.g. this example you see they have it on their primary key:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was not saving because the mage2gen generator added wrong values for the ID in the files, because my table name ends with `_quote` and it took it to make `quote_id` to the ID key..., but I am already using `quote_id` as a field, so it does not work out...

- Company/Shipping/Model/ResourceModel/Quote/Collection.php
- Company/Shipping/Model/ResourceModel/Quote.php

I also have set `identity='true'` like @Kristoffer suggested.

Comment: I double checked it, and it was indeed the reason. I also set `identity='true'` like @Kristoffer suggested.